# Jenkins as process starter

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, process

I wanted to ask if anyone has gained experienced by using Jenkins for starting (Java/Maven) processes? How is your company starting processes on their application servers?

Currently we are using `ant` to start the application, but are searching for a replacement that offers

- traceability / logging
- ease of access (Webinterface or GUI for the production department)

Jenkins came in mind because I know it, but I'm not sure if this is the right tool for this purpose.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/)

It can run local and remote tasks, jobs, etc.

Comment: Well this looks promising and I'll definitely try this out!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use jenkins for both.

> traceability / logging

Using Audit2DB plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Audit+To+Database+Plugin), you can log all build/job details into a db and can fetch/create a report. Customize the schema as per requirement.

> ease of access (Webinterface or GUI for the production department)

Again a yes. By implementing propert folders/views and access-control it is possible.

More, I have used Jenkins server a centralized build/deploy/test as an orchestrator to initiate a build, deploy on remote hosts (tomcat based java apps) and run test cases.